# How do I remove Firefox Nightly?

Tags: 12.04, installation, firefox, beta

How to remove/uninstall Firefox Nightly build, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. Made an error, I'm supposed to be installing Firefox 13.

Comment: did you add the ppa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the nightly build of Firefox https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa then to remove the nightly build of Firefox run this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox-trunk
```

Answer (score 3):

***You need to undo what you did to get the nightly builds in the first place.***

for example: (may not exactly match your setup)

install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/thunderbird-aurora

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

downgrade

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge      (if required)

sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/thunderbird-aurora
```

Then just update you system.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```